# How to select child and parent categories by type

Tags: mysql

How can i select child and parent categories where type = 1 ?

**For example:**

TV (type = 0) -> LED (type = 1) -> QLED (type = 1) -> 32inc (type = 0)

TV (type = 0) -> LED (type = 1) -> QLED (type = 1) -> 24inc (type = 1)

Phone (type = 1) -> LG (type = 1) ->  A100 (type = 1)

Phone (type = 1) -> LG (type = 1) ->  C300 (type = 1)

**Im looking to get result like**

LED -> QLED

LED -> QLED -> 24inc

Phone -> LG -> A100

Phone -> LG -> C300

If parent/child is not type = 1 shouldn`t exist in return results but their child should exist in result if type = 1

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb7ee1)

```
        CREATE TABLE `menu` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `main_cat` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `room` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT ' 0 = False, 1 = True',
      `type` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT ' 0 = False, 1 = True',
      `sort_order` int(11) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


    INSERT INTO `menu` (`id`, `name`, `main_cat`, `room`, `type`, `sort_order`) VALUES
    (21, 'TV', 0, 1, 0,  1),
    (22, 'LED', 21,  0, 1, 1),
    (23, 'QLED', 21, 0, 1, 0),
    (24, '24inc', 23, 0, 1, 0),
    (25, '32inc', 23, 1, 0, 0),
    (26, 'Phone', 0, 0, 1, 2),
    (27, 'LG', 26, 0, 1, 2),
    (28, 'A100', 27, 0, 1, 1),
    (29, 'C300', 27, 0, 1, 1),
    (55, 'PC', 0, 1, 1, 3),
    (56, 'HP', 55, 0, 1, 2);


    ALTER TABLE `menu`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

        SELECT 
      m1.id AS main_id, m1.name AS main_name, 
      m2.id AS sub_id, m2.name AS sub_name, 
      m3.id AS subsub_id, m3.name AS susub_name 
    FROM menu m1
      LEFT JOIN menu m2 ON m2.main_cat = m1.id
      LEFT JOIN menu m3 ON m3.main_cat = m2.id
    WHERE m1.main_cat = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your where clause in inner SQL:

```
 SELECT 
      m1.id AS main_id, m1.name AS main_name, 
      m2.id AS sub_id, m2.name AS sub_name, 
      m3.id AS subsub_id, m3.name AS susub_name 
    FROM menu m1
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM menu where type=1) m2 ON m2.main_cat = m1.id
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM menu where type=1) m3 ON m3.main_cat = m2.id
    WHERE m1.main_cat = 0
```

Or use my method if I understand carefully

```
 SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT m1.name as name1, m2.name as name2 FROM menu m1
 LEFT JOIN menu m2
 on m1.id = m2.main_cat
 where m2.type = 1
) A 
left join (
 SELECT m1.name as name1, m2.name as name2 FROM menu m1
 LEFT JOIN menu m2
 on m1.id = m2.main_cat
 where m2.type = 1
) B
on A.name2 = b.name1
```

Or in a better way use temporary table

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpTable SELECT m1.name as name1, m2.name as name2 FROM menu m1
 LEFT JOIN menu m2
 on m1.id = m2.main_cat
 where m2.type = 1;
 
 SELECT A.name1, A.name2,B.name2 FROM tmpTable A 
left join tmpTable B
on A.name2 = b.name1
```

EDIT==================
Add type qualifier for rows:

```
SELECT A.name1, A.name2, B.name2 FROM (
 SELECT m1.name as name1, m2.name as name2 FROM menu m1
 LEFT JOIN menu m2
 on m1.id = m2.main_cat
 where m1.type = 1 and m2.type = 1
) A 
left join (
 SELECT m1.name as name1, m2.name as name2 FROM menu m1
 LEFT JOIN menu m2
 on m1.id = m2.main_cat
) B
on A.name2 = b.name1
```

Comment: query returns TV -> LED -> QLED when should be only LED -> QLED because only this child/parent are type = 1

Comment: You can modify it simply. I cannot understand your question correctly because I see phone is added in list. If you have any problem I can do it for you.

Comment: Phone is added in list because type = 1 but TV type = 0 so this should be not add in list . If parent/child is not type = 1 shouldn`t exist in return results but their child should exist in result if type = 1

Comment: I add new query but i cannot understand what is relation between LED and QLED. They are just have same parents.  If same parent is a relation why  A100->C300 is not in your desired output???

Comment: sorry my bad dude you are correct thank you